# Jelly Bean Digital Clock

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to make a Clock like Jelly bean (hours in bold and minutes normal) like this image:
[image]

i downloaded the EditClock widget from Android openSource, The clock works, but i cant make th "Bold" work im using this code:
[EditClock Source Code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.2_r1/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/DigitalClock.java)
im ussing the Jelly Bean Fonts.
and this is part of my layout

```
<com.myApp.views.DigitalClock
        android:id="@+id/digitalClock1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/musicDashboard"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
        
         <TextView android:id="@+id/timeDisplayBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/clock_text_size"
           
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
           android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/timeDisplayForeground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="none"
             android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/timeDisplayBackground"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timeDisplayBackground"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
            android:textSize="@dimen/clock_text_size"
            />
    </com.myApp.views.DigitalClock>
```

How i can make this work? in Gingerbread and Up?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the code for the DigitalClock widget to add a Span around the first part of the text. Try this code in the `updateTime()` method:

```
CharSequence newTime = DateFormat.format(mFormat, mCalendar);
SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(newTime);
int endIndex = spannable.indexOf(':');
spannable.setSpan(new StylePan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, endIndex, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
mTimeDisplayBackground.setText(spannable);
mTimeDisplayForeground.setText(spannable);
mAmPm.setIsMorning(mCalendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0);
```

Comment: Yes, it Works, but, the Bold it sighly different than minutes, its any way where the minutes being thinner than Hours?

Comment: Android doesn't provide a mechanism to "make it bolder" or "make it thinner". All you have to work with are the Typeface style constants like the one used in the code snippet. You could try using a custom typeface if you really think it's worth it.

Comment: seems i cant make it work :( at least not as i want, perhaps its a good aproach that "looks" like what i want thanks